# Any way to test the Datasource in Websphere Liberty as in tradtional?

Tags: datasource, websphere-liberty

I am switching from Websphere 8.5.5.0 to 8.5.5.9. I have two questions on the datasource configuratioin.

- Do I have to use JAAS in liberty or the `<properties.oracle
  user="xxx" password="yyy" URL=zzz/>`is sufficient?
- Is there a test datasource button in the Liberty adminCenter like
  it's in the traditional admin console?

Comment: as of the April 2017 Liberty beta, testing data source connections is now possible.  See this blog post: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2017/04/19/testing-database-connections/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use JAAS for your datasource authentication with Liberty, but if you use userid and password properties, you should at least [use the tools to encrypt them](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_sec_considerations.html?lang=en) to provide a minimal level of security.
Liberty Admin Center doesn't yet have a "Test Connection" button like traditional Admin Console, but you can RESTfully test a datasource using the new function described in this wasdev [blog](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2017/04/19/testing-database-connections/).